# javascript $ followed by curly braces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read a book called "Javascript web application" and it has the following lines of code:

> The example below, which includes logic inside views, is something you shouldn’t do:

```
<div>
<script>
function formatDate(date) {
/* ... */
};
</script>
${ formatDate(this.date) }
</div>
```

I don't understand what { formatDate(this.date) } means in javascript even in jQuery I have never seen it yet (putting object in jQuery function then I've already seen but the above code is not the case). 
Could you explain me what the meaning of it?
Thank you.

Comment: It just says it's something you shouldn't do, and to the best of my knowledge, can't do.

Comment: This is not valid syntax. The call isn't even in the scope of the `<script>` tag so you have no reference to the `$ object` as it's attached to the `window` and the window can only be referenced `inline, within script tags, or in a .js document`.

Comment: The `${ }` bit is not Javascript. It looks like it's meant to be part of some template syntax to be expanded by the template processor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`${}` is a Template Tag, used by [jQuery Template Plugin](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/).

> **${} Template Tag**
>
> Used for insertion of data values in the rendered
> template. Evaluates the specified field (property) on the current data
> item, or the specified JavaScript function or expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bit more than this: Indeed, the jQuery Template Plugin used to have this syntax `${}`. However, currently, this is part of the ES 6 (aka EcmaScript 2015) standard.

Reference: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html